# SAS - How to skip certain columns in a loop using arrays

Tags: arrays, if-statement, sas

I have a dataset that contains several numeric and character columns. Most of the character columns are simple 'yes' or 'no' questions but some are not. For the numeric columns I feel that I have a valid solution. For the character columns I have tried to minimize it but have not succeeded. **What I want to do**, and tried, is a loop that states that when *j = column number of var4* then use the Big/Small/IU replacements. The idea is that this would make the code less “variable dependent” due to the fact that I can change the variable for var4 in the %let statement and the code would be shorter in length.

As the dim statement give me the total number of the numeric or character columns I guess that there are some statment that gives me the column placement of a specific variable that I would use for the secound loop. However, I have not found such a statement.

My code so far,

```
%let v1 = var1;
%let v2 = var2;
%let v3 = var3;
%let v4 = var4;

data have;
infile datalines delimiter = '|'; 
input surveyYear id var1 var2$ var3 var4$20. ;
datalines;
2016 |  1 |     10 |   Yes |     5 |   BIG
2016 |  2 |      6 |   YES |     8 |   Big
2016 |  3 |      8 |   YEs | 99999 |   big
2016 |  4 |      . |   yes |     5 | 99999
2017 |  5 |      6 |    No |     7 | SMALL
2017 |  6 |      5 |    Ye |     . | small
2017 |  7 |  99999 |    no |     3 | 99999
2018 |  8 |      3 | 99999 |     1 | SMall
2018 |  9 |      2 |    iu |     2 |    IU
2018 | 10 |     15 |    IU |     . |    Iu
;
run; 

data want;
set have;

    array var_num[*] _numeric_;
    do i=3 to dim(var_num);
        if var_num[i] = 99999 then var_num[i] = .;
    end;

    array var_cha[*] _character_;
    do j=1 to dim(var_cha);
        var_cha(j) = upcase(var_cha(j));
        if var_cha[j]  = 'YES'     then var_cha[j] = 'Yes';
        if var_cha[j]  = 'NO'      then var_cha[j] = 'No';
        if var_cha[j]  = 'IU'      then var_cha[j] = 'IU';
        if var_cha[j]  = '99999'   then var_cha[j] = 'IU';
        if var_cha[j]  = ''        then var_cha[j] = 'IU';
    end;
/* Integrate the code below into the loop*/
    if &v4 = 'BIG'     then &v4 = 'Big city';
    if &v4 = 'SMALL'   then &v4 = 'Small city';
    if &v4 = 'IU'      then &v4 = 'Unknow city size';
    if &v4 = '99999'   then &v4 = 'Unknow city size';

drop i j;
run;
```

The conceptual idea how i would like to program it,

```
data want;
set have;
array var_cha[*] _character_;
    do j=1 to dim(var_cha);
        var_cha(j) = upcase(var_cha(j));
/*      All of the if statements for the yes, no and IU */

        if var_cha[j] = ColumnNumerOfVar4 then do;
        /* where ColumnNumerOfVar4 is equal to the column number of var4*/
            if var_cha[j] =  'BIG'      then var_cha[j] = 'Big city';
            if var_cha[j] =  'SMALL'    then var_cha[j] = 'Small city';
            if var_cha[j] =  'IU'       then var_cha[j] = 'Unknow city size';
            if var_cha[j] =  '99999'    then var_cha[j] = 'Unknow city size';
        end;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: I think you want the VNAME() function to test if a variable is what you think it is?

Comment: I don’t want to test if the variable is what I think it is. I would like to have their numeric position. In my example dim(var_cha) would give me a max j of 3. J=1 would be the numeric position of all character columns for var2 and J=2 would give me the numeric position of all character columns for var4. What I want is to put the numeric position of var4 (in this example 2) in X and then state that if var_cha[j]=X then do the following if statements. But I don’t know how to find X.

Comment: Honestly, it's not clear what you're trying to do. J is the index so that's the position of the variable in the array. The variety of answers shows that others are also unclear as to what you're asking.

Comment: I thought I explained it better but you are right as the variety of answers show! What I’m trying to is loop thru a certain amount of numeric and character variables but skip over a specific variable among these. Let’s say that I have 10 character variables. 8 of these variables have simple yes or no answers but 2 of the character variables have the same input (for example big and small) but should have different output (big would be Big City in one variable but Big cake in the other).

Comment: What I try to do is to determine a way to, in the loop, to replace these 2 variables with their specific text. In other word integrate the last part of the code in the first code (My code so far headline) into the loop. My code that I posted will do the thing I need it to do but I thought it would be cleaner if everything was in the loop. In matlab I could determine it by [row col]. I hope this made it clearer?

Comment: If different variables need to be treated differently, you have a few options. One is to set them as different arrays. In SAS an array is just a short cut reference so not much issue with adding overhead here. In your case, can you use a format instead of recoding? You can also simplify some of your code using IN.  `if var_cha(j) in ('IU', '99999', '') then do....`. You may also want to make those `if/then/else` which will be slightly faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get a name of a variable in an array, you can use vName function:

```
    if (vName(var_cha[j]) = 'var4') then do;
    /* where ColumnNumberOfVar4 is equal to the column number of var4*/
        if var_cha[j] =  'BIG'      then var_cha[j] = 'Big city';
        if var_cha[j] =  'SMALL'    then var_cha[j] = 'Small city';
        if var_cha[j] =  'IU'       then var_cha[j] = 'Unknow city size';
        if var_cha[j] =  '99999'    then var_cha[j] = 'Unknow city size';
    end;
```

As I understand this will solve your problem. But if you also want to get the column number of a specific variable, you can do it either by looking into the sasHelp.vColumns and putting the number in a macro variable. Or do something like this at the beginning of your data step:

```
retain columnNumberOfVar4;
if (_n_ eq 1) then do;
    id = open("work.have","i");
    num = attrn(id,"nvars");
    columnNumberOfVar4 = varNum(id, 'var4');
    rc = close(id);
end;
```

But I believe this is not what you need to do in your case.

Comment: It feels that this could be close to what I want but you determine the position by it's variable name insted of its numeric position. However when I try to run the code it says "Expecting an arithmetic operator." for the if statment

Comment: Which part runs with the error? I think I checked both. To get variable position by its name you can use varNum(id, 'var4'). It will give you position of a variable with name 'var4' in a dataset.

Comment: if (vName(var_cha[j]) = 'var4' then do; Gets the error. Says that the 'var4'  expecting an arithmetic operator.

Comment: It looks like this is an old version. Sorry at the beginning I made a mistake an missed a closing brace. It should be **(vName(var_cha[j]) = 'var4')**

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Is this normal procedure for SAS to refer to the variable name instead? In other program languages I have always referred to its numeric position. It achieves the same output but the thinking is different.

Comment: It depends on the task, but in most situations I refer to a variable name and not its position. In my opinion the array functionality in SAS/Base is very poor, so you have to work with SAS datasets (tables) and refer to all variables by name.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I am not understanding exactly what you want, but it looks like you just want to make a macro variable with the list of variable names that the DO loop applies to and use that to define the array.

```
%let yesnovars=var4 ;
array yesno &yesnovars;
```

Then you DO loop looks like this:

```
 do j=1 to dim(yesno);
    yesno(j) = upcase(yesno(j));
    if yesno[j]  = 'YES'     then yesno[j] = 'Yes';
    if yesno[j]  = 'NO'      then yesno[j] = 'No';
    if yesno[j]  = 'IU'      then yesno[j] = 'IU';
    if yesno[j]  = '99999'   then yesno[j] = 'IU';
    if yesno[j]  = ''        then yesno[j] = 'IU';
 end;
```

But it really looks like you just want to apply formats to the values.
So if you had defined a $YESNO format and a $CITYSIZE format you might do something like this to convert all of the character variables from the raw to formatted values.  Just remember to define them as long enough to hold the formatted values instead of just the raw values.

```
format var2 $yesno. var4 $citysize.;
array _c _character_;
do j=1 to dim(_c);
  _c(j)=vvalue(_c(i));
end;
```

Or even better define INformats and use them when reading the raw data.

Comment: I already have the code to replace the yes, no and IU part. What I would like to is to integrate the big/small/IU into the loop but state in the loop that if j equals a certain variable (eg. Var4) then do some other stud instead. I have for example in my real data set several variables that have the same input (big, small or IU) but they mean different things. Therefore I am wondering if there is a easy way to determine the column position of these variables. MATLAB have for example [row col]

Comment: What I am saying is does NOT need to be in the same loop.  Make a separate array and loop for every class of variable you want to recode. That would be much clearer.